# How to implement prepared statement in Zend Framework Database Query Functions

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I am learning the Zend Framework. Now I need to attach a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection in the Zend Framework.
So I am sharing some functions here which I am using so if you can tell me how I can attach a prepared statement in these Zend Database Query Functions it will be helpful.

```
public function getRowByID($id) {
        $row = $this->fetchRow("id =  '$id'");
        if (!$row) {
            return false;
        }
        return $row;
    }

public function getbyProjectID($projectid) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM auth where projectid = '$projectid'";

        $result = $this->getAdapter()->query($query);
        return $result->fetchAll();
    }

public function updateRowByUserProject($username, $projectid) {

        $query = "UPDATE auth SET iscurrent=0 WHERE username = '$username'";

        $result = $this->getAdapter()->query($query);

        $query1 = "UPDATE auth SET iscurrent=1 WHERE username = '$username' AND projectid = '$projectid'";

        $result1 = $this->getAdapter()->query($query1);
        $affectedRow = $result1->rowCount();
        if($affectedRow == 1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please, **stop** putting random tags on this question. Select a single version of zend framework, there is no need to pop this question on all versions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fetching you could use Zend_Db_Select Class methods for preparing a query and executing it, passing variables in questionmark places (placeholders which will be escaped from special characters) after comma (possible multiple questionmarks, passing variables from left to right):

```
public function getRowByID($id) {
        $table = $this->getTable();
        $select = $table->select();

        $select->where('id = ?', $id);

        $row = $table->fetchRow($select);

        if (!$row) {
            return false;
        }
        return $row;
    }
```

For your second method getByProjectId() it depends if you are in proper model (like Auth_Model_Auth) or you want to access data from another table

```
public function getbyProjectID($projectid) {
    $table = $this->getTable();
    $select = $table->select();

    $select->where('projectid = ?', $projectid);

    $result = $table->fetchAll($select);
    return $result;
}
```

And for updating you can pass an array to 'update' method in same style like for fetching data. Key of an array must be a column name of your table.

```
public function updateRowByUserProject($username, $projectid) {
    $table = $this->getTable();

    // Data you want to insert/update
    $data = [
        'iscurrent' => 0
    ];

    // Where you want to update it
    $where = [
        'username = ?' => $username
    ]

    $result = $table->update($data, $where);

    $data1 = [
        'iscurrent' => 1
    ]

    $where1 = [
        'username = ?' => $username,
        'projectid = ?' => $projectid
    ]

    $result1 = $table->update($data1, $where1);
}
```

EDIT:

For both questions from comments you could achieve this by using quoteInto method, which also escapes data from special chars.

In first case you prepare a $where variable, which contains what record you want to delete:

```
$table = $this->getTable();
$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('projectid = ?', $projectid); 

$isDeleted = $table->delete($where);
```

In second case you can do exactly the same:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM applications WHERE projectid IN (SELECT projectid FROM auth WHERE projectid = ?)";
$query = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto(?, $projectid):
...
```

But you should try to avoid writing big queries in one variable and then executing them. I would suggest you to get to know with this:
https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.select.html

Really well explained how to use Zend methods for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, @Karol, It's Working.
I have one more question we need prepared statements in delete queries also or not.

Comment: And how I will do prepared statement IN clause

public function countbyProject($projectid) {
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM applications WHERE projectid IN (SELECT projectid FROM auth WHERE projectid='$projectid')";
        
        $result = $this->getAdapter()->query($query);
        $row = $result->fetchObject();
        return $row->total;
    }

Comment: I edited my answer @coder_yogi cause it was too long for writing it in comment. Check upper